# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS freeze when shutdown

Tags: boot, nvidia, 18.04, shutdown, freeze

I have an Alienware 17R4 laptop with Nvidia Geforece Gtx 1070. Yesterday I tried a lot of way to install Ubuntu dual boot with my windows 10, and finally installed it (version 18.04) after changing the acpi=off. However, now my Ubuntu faces a problem that is it freeze whenever I shutdown it normally, and force me to hold the power button to shutdown. If I restart, ubuntu works fine but shutdown leads to freezing. I googled it and someone said that I have to change the acpi=force, but because I have to set acpi=off to install Ubuntu, I'm afraid that if I set acpi=force I cannot start Ubuntu again.

Thanks for any help.